Firestore collection query filter by document path REST API
I have a Firestore database structured as follow:
/collection1/<docid1>/collection2/<docid2>/field1 (authenticated user)
/collection3/<docid2>/field2 (restricted access)

I would like to retrieve only all the documents in collection2 under collection1 that have a specific value for field1.
I can do the query from the query builder by using a "Collection group" and filtering on the "Document Id" and the field1, but when I try the equivalent from the the REST API via :runQuery
{
  "structuredQuery": {
    "from": [{
      "allDescendants": true,
      "collectionId": "collection2"
    }],
    "orderBy": [{
      "direction": "ASCENDING",
      "field": {
        "fieldPath": "field3"
      }
    }],
    "where": {
      "compositeFilter": {
        "filters": [{
          "fieldFilter": {
            "field": {
              "fieldPath": "field1"
            },
            "op": "EQUAL",
            "value": {
              "stringValue": "<something>"
            }
          }
        }, {
          "fieldFilter": {
            "field": {
              "fieldPath": "uid"
            },
            "op": "LESS_THAN",
            "value": {
              "stringValue": "/collection1/z"
            }
          }
        }, {
          "fieldFilter": {
            "field": {
              "fieldPath": "uid"
            },
            "op": "GREATER_THAN",
            "value": {
              "stringValue": "/collection1/0"
            }
          }
        }],
        "op": "AND"
      }
    }
  }
}

I keep getting
"error": {
   "code": 403,
   "message": "Missing or insufficient permissions.",
   "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}

Rules are as follow (I mention only the read permission for simplicity)
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /collection1/{docid1} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
      match /collection2/{docid2} {
        allow read: if request.auth != null;
      }
    }
    match /collection3/{docid2} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == docid2;
    }
  }
}


Is uid the equivalent of Document ID in the collection query builder? If not is there a way to filter by Document ID as the query builder?

I suspect that the REST API is searching (allDescendants = true) in depth and for this reason it tries to look into /collection3 for collection2. Is there a way to tell the query to limit the search only to the path /collection1?



The equivalent of the Document ID field in the query builder is "__NAME__".

To allow a collection group query, you need rules with a match clause like those shown in the documentation on Secure and query documents based on collection groups:
match /{path=**}/[COLLECTION_ID]/{doc}

The path=** part is what ensures it matches the collection group query, as this rule matches whatever name you put for [COLLECTION_ID] wherever it exists in the database.

To limit to a certain path, you can do a path-prefix filter like shown here:  CollectionGroupQuery but limit search to subcollections under a particular document
